# How to randomize the position of an element when clicked

Tags: javascript, events, random

I'm making a basic game. I need this circle, when clicked, to move another random position on the screen.

The rest of the game : https://codepen.io/jtog95/pen/ExPbzvo

```
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
var spaceWidth;
var spaceHeight;

initCircle();

function initCircle() {
  spaceWidth = screen.height - circle.height;
  spaceHeight = screen.width - circle.width;

  circle.addEventListener('click', moveCircle)
}

function moveCircle(){
  circle.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceWidth) + 'px';

  circle.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceHeight) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Use `parseInt(circle.style.height)` to get a number.
This will "convert" `100px` to `100`.
No need to add `px` when assigning value - it's the default (you could use `%`, `em`, etc., but not for this matter).

Comment: You kinda mixed things up here: `spaceWidth = screen.height - circle.height;
  spaceHeight = screen.width - circle.width;`...

Comment: and also mixed here: `circle.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceWidth) + 'px';

  circle.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceHeight) + 'px';`

Comment: If it still doesn't "move" - check if you remembered to set `style.position="absolute"`.

Comment: Also, change `screen.height` to `document.body.offsetHeight`.

Comment: height | width | top | left - use the one you need with what's in my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML with CSS (for my testing, use what you want, must use `position`):

```
<div id="circle" style="position: absolute; height: 25px; width: 25px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
var spaceWidth;
var spaceHeight;

function initCircle() {
  spaceWidth = document.body.offsetHeight - parseInt(circle.style.height);
  spaceHeight = document.body.offsetWidth - parseInt(circle.style.width);
  circle.addEventListener('click', moveCircle)
}

function moveCircle() {
  circle.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceWidth) + 'px';
  circle.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * spaceHeight) + 'px';
}

initCircle();
```

Click away! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see a couple of issues.  First is the fact that circle.width and circle.height are undefined.  You should probably use clientHeight and clientWidth instead.  The second issue I see is in the move circle.  You need to set the position to absolute or relative if you're going to use top and left.  Once you have these changes in place, you'll notice another issue, the ball can go out of bounds.  This is because you're using screen.width rather than window.innerWidth (and vice-versa for height).